How to create a deep link in an app made with android compose if i don't have a website for my app
I am creating an app that should  enable the  users to share their profile or posts through links.
The user should be able to (by pressing a share button) create a content specific link for any of his/her posts.
And if anyone clicks that link , he/she should be redirected to that specific part of the app .
And if the app is not installed on his/her device , he/she must be redirected to the app store to install the app.
And if the user tries to open that shared link in a desktop, there should be a way to handle it (still i don't have a website).
After surfing a bit , I found that Firebase Dynamic Links was an option but it has been deprecated and will not be in function after 25 August 2025.
So, how do i implement the desired feature in my app ?

You can implement deep links even though u don't have an website. You have to register the schema and the path you want to follow in android manifest and handle it in your navigation library or what are you using.
